# When exporting data to an Excel file, how to make the export of large data faster?

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, export

I am currently exporting the data (around 2 million) to an Excel file, but it takes a long time. I would like the export to take less time.

During Debug I see when the slowdown occurs.
I would like to make it faster.

We have data with specific column names and an index, and during export they are exported with the names of the columns that correspond precisely to them.

| Different column | Value | ROW_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| headerA | 9.5 | 1 |
| headerB | 10 | 1 |
| headerC | 3 | 1 |
| headerA | 8 | 2 |
| headerB | 7 | 2 |
| headerC | 4.5 | 2 |
| headerA | 11 | 3 |
| headerB | 9 | 3 |
| headerC | 5 | 3 |

Rendered on the Excel file:

| ROW_ID | headerA | headerB | headerC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9.5 | 10 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 | 7 | 4.5 |
| 3 | 11 | 9 | 5 |

```
private DataSource GetDatasForRequestWSData(RequestWSData requestWSData, IEnumerable<int> listIndexRow, bool isExport = false)
{
    DataSource result = new DataSource();
    try
    {
        if (listIndexRow != null)
        {
            int totalIndex = listIndexRow.Count();

            if (totalIndex > 0)
            {
                var sourceName = requestWSData.Endpoints[0].EndpointName;
                //Pagination
                listIndexRow = listIndexRow.OrderBy(x => x).Skip(requestWSData.From).Take(requestWSData.PageSize);

                //Get datas with selected indices and order them
                var finalDatas = _datas.Where(x => x.SOURCE_NOM.Equals(sourceName) && listIndexRow.Contains(x.INDEX_ROW_ID)).OrderBy(x => x.INDEX_ROW_ID);


                //Eliminate duplicates, This is where it takes a long time 
                var distinctDatasList = finalDatas.GroupBy(m => new { m.INDEX_ROW_ID, m.ATTRIBUT_NOM }).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First());


                var columns = new List<AttributInfo>();

                //Get all information 
                columns = (from colonne in distinctDatasList
                           select new AttributInfo
                           {
                               indexRow = colonne.Value.INDEX_ROW_ID,
                               AttributName = colonne.Value.ATTRIBUT_NOM,
                               AttributValue = colonne.Value.ATTRIBUT_VALEUR
                           }).ToList();

                var data = finalDatas.FirstOrDefault();
                result = new DataSource
                {
                    SOURCE_ID = data.SOURCE_ID,
                    INDEX_ROW_ID = data.INDEX_ROW_ID,
                    SOURCE_NOM = data.SOURCE_NOM,
                    Attributs = columns,
                    listIndexRow = listIndexRow.ToList(),
                    Total = totalIndex
                };

            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Error("OPEN SAFETY SQL Search Infrastructure ==> GetDatasForRequestWSData() -- " + e.Message);
        _log.Error("OPEN SAFETY SQL Search Infrastructure ==> GetDatasForRequestWSData() -- " + e.StackTrace);
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I tried to perform data processing, block by block processing, or split the code steps. I also wanted to parse with a pageSize so that the data recovered is processed every 1000 lines if the PageSize = 1000.

but I'm going in circles... do you have any ideas? please.

Comment: "This is where it takes a long time" - yes, but that line causes the execution of the two previous lines too, which have up to that point been deferred (because they do not enumerate) and both contain an OrderBy. If your claim to the size of the dataset is correct, the first line is ordering 2 million items, which is no small undertaking. Read up about "LINQ deferred execution". I'd skip the ordering, and perhaps build items into a SortedDictionary, just straight enumerating the 2 million; you don't need to dedupe, as the dictionary will do that implicitly because it can only store unique keys